# Not receiving URL variables in controller with GET, codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal, get

I'm not receiving variables in my controller from a URL from Paypal indicating a successful transaction. They appear in the URL fine but my controller is not receiving them for some odd reason. I think the code is absolutely correct. What could be the reason?

Example:

Received URL: http://example.com/Paypal/success?tx=8FA47070HF454623K&st=Completed&amt=20%2e00&cc=USD&cm=&item_number=

**Controller, PHP:**

```
function success(){
        //get the transaction data
        $paypalInfo = $this->input->get();


             $data['item_number'] = $paypalInfo["item_number"];
             $data['txn_id'] = $paypalInfo["tx"];
             $data['payment_amt'] = $paypalInfo["amt"];
             $data['currency_code'] = $paypalInfo["cc"];
             $data['status'] = $paypalInfo["st"];

             //pass the transaction data to view
             $this->load->view('paypal/success', $data);
     }
```

I get this result for all variables:

[image]

Comment: set in config  `$config['allow_get_array'] = TRUE;`

Comment: splash58, It is already true.

Answer (score 0):

Remember Paypal not send data via URL, So you couldn't receive data via `GET` method. You should try this

```
$paypalInfo = $this->input->post();
```

instead what you are using now. If it not works then use following

```
$paypalInfo = $_POST;
```

it will must work

Comment: rm is set to 2 but Paypal still sends data through GET if "Payment Data Transfer" is enabled. Doing it using POST doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like item_number is not set. Performing a GET on it can cause an error.

You are using a class function to obtain the `$_GET` items.

Within the function `$this->input->get()` you should check if the var is available (`if(isset($_GET[..]))`) and otherwise return a default, so you don't run into these problems.

On the other hand, it seems that you don't submit a item_number to Pay Pal. May also be a problem for processing your order later on in the script and backtracing it to the original...

---- ALSO SEE ANSWER BELOW ----

Paypal sends POST vars...

Comment: Tried all the suggestions. The problem remains. :(

Answer (score 0):

Just processing $_POST gives you a huge security risk! Also for  $_GET. Change $_POST to $_GET below to use $_GET in stead of $_POST.

I would suggest at least the following;

```
foreach ($_POST as $key->$value)
{
$cleankey = addslashes($key);
$paypalInfo[$cleankey] = addslashes($value);
}
```

Then;

```
 $req_keys = array(
'item_number' => 'item_number',
'txn_id' => 'tx',
'payment_amt' => 'amt',
'currency_code' => 'cc',
'status' => 'st',
);
$data = array();
$error = array();
foreach($req_keys as $req_data_key=>$req_paypalinfo_key )
{
     if(isset($paypalInfo[$req_paypalinfo_key]))
     {
         $data[$req_data_key] = $paypalInfo[$req_paypalinfo_key];
     }
     else
     {
         $error[] = "missing POST data:".$req_paypalinfo_key;
     }
}
if(count($error) > 0)
{
     var_dump($error);
}
else
{
      $this->load->view('paypal/success', $data);
}
```

This will give you insight if your required info is there and also gives you some protection against SQL injection.